# conda list -f --json spyder creates huge load

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, load, conda

I do use anaconda on an ubuntu 20.04 and since a week or so I have a problem with processes like

```html
/home/csi/anaconda3/bin/python /home/csi/anaconda3/bin/conda list -f --json spyder
```

creating a huge load between 40 und 160. The number of processes is about 110.
I have been using 4 environments created by ananconda-navigator all of them are Python 3-Projects, none of them is called spyder. One is called spyder5.
I am using the activation of conda python with the delivered .bashrc-snippet.

```html
:~$  conda list conda
# packages in environment at /home/csi/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2020.07                  py38_0  
anaconda                  custom                   py38_1  
anaconda-client           1.9.0            py38h06a4308_0  
anaconda-navigator        2.1.2            py38h06a4308_0  
anaconda-project          0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
conda                     4.11.0           py38h06a4308_0  
conda-build               3.20.5                   py38_1  
conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py38h27cfd23_1  
conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
```

The process starts automatically again after a while. So to work without that huge load I created a bash script trying to kill all those processes every ten seconds.

I did not try to uninstall anaconda3 and recreate all Environments. I will do this when I am upgrading the Ubuntu-Version in May anyway.

But does anyone have had an issue alike? Or does anyone know howto deactivate the periodically start of conda list? This is really annoying.

If you need more information I would be happy to provide them for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a while an update of conda fixed this issue. However, this was strange behaviour.

I did reinstall spyder via pip3 command of the anaconda installation. After that I updated anaconda and conda via conda command.

```
:~$ pip3 install --force-reinstall spyder
:~$ conda update anaconda
:~$ conda update conda
```

This fixed the issue of "conda list" processes but not the issue of the one process creating a huge load. However now the system is usable again.